# rasterio pass custom properties in profile

Tags: python, rasterio

I am trying to construct rasterio files, starting from a numpy array which contains multiple bands, and a profile:

```
meta = {
        'driver': 'GTiff',
        'dtype': rasterio.float32,
        'nodata': None,
        'width': 100, 
        'height': 100,
        'count': 16,
        'crs': CRS.from_epsg(4326),
        'transform': rasterio.Affine(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
        'custom_ids': {'p1', 'p2'}  # Custom property
    }
    mem_file = rasterio.MemoryFile()
    with mem_file.open(**meta) as dataset:
        dataset.write(raster_data)
```

The memfile gets created but the profile custom property is not passed along. Is there a way to achive this - I want to pass some extra metadata in the file, so that after I persist it on disk and open it again, I get that 'custom_ids' property back.

I've looked into extending the Profile class and adding the custom property to the defaults, but that also didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have read the rasterio documentation a bit more carefully. The mechanism for passing custom properties in a raster is called a tag.

```
dataset.update_tags(a='1', b='2')
```

Details [here](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/tags.html)